Hex characters are showing up when reading html via swift in URLSession
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    guard let (data, response) = try? await self.data(from: url) else {
      return nil
    }
    
    guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
      return nil
    }
    
    guard response.statusCode == 200 else {
      return nil
    }

    guard var htmlString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
      return nil
    }
    
    print(htmlString)

Here inside the html string i want to parse a  tag to extract the json inside it.
Here is how its inside postman.
<script nonce="T8p1Whosq0Ane44rpGoEag">var ytInitialData = {
    "responseContext": {...}

</script>

Here is how it in swift when i print the html string
<script nonce="QLqR5IUqHc6l2EXG5KU1uw">var ytInitialData = '\x7b\x22responseContext\x22:\x7b\x22
...
</script>

here url is https://www.youtube.com

That’s just it’s Unicode value left   bracket \x7b https://www.codetable.net/hex/7b

Ever considered the idea that YouTube might give you different results depending on your request headers?

Setting a User-Agent header seems to make YouTube return the expected HTML without hex escape sequences.

I added the User-Agent field, but response is still the same. I know its a unicode char for left bracket, but i need to convert it to json object via JSONSerialization. Its failing to convert it.
